# Using URL contents to send data(post or get) to a PHP page

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mod-rewrite

OK, I am creating a questionnaire application that is managed by a single user on /manage. There, he can create multiple questionnaires, each with a different name and set of settings(registered users, questions, data, etc.). Currently, the different tests are accessed by non-administrative users(the takers of the test) by going to /index.php?t=Questionnaire%20Name. Obviously, this is not the best interface to give to users. I would like for the users to be able to access that test by going to /QuestonnaireName. I feel like this could be done with mod-rewrite, but I don't know how to use it or where to start. I've coded the entire thing in JS, PHP, and MySQL. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a example to get you going:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1
```

Put this in a file called `.htaccess` in the same directory as index.php. Now everything you call will be routed to index.php, and you can get hold of the url with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`. Then you are free to do anything you want with it.

Alternative way, to save you from making edits to index.php:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?t=$1
```

Notice the `t=` after the `index.php?`. Now everything can be found from `$_GET['t']`, but I can't guarantee this will be foolproof as I have not used this method myself. Test it out and see if it works for you.

**EDIT**

Edited to allow access to physical directories.

Comment: Thanks, that worked almost exactly as I wanted it too. Really cool. However, when you try to access /manage, obviously mod_rewrite catches it and just sends you to index.php. Is there a way I can put an if statement in?

Comment: Additionally, when I try to access /manager, the URL bar reports /manager/?t=manager. This does not happen for anything else I've tried, and /manager is the only subdirectory.

Comment: I found out how to accomplish this. All it takes is another RewriteCond, exactly the same as the other one, but with -d, instead of -f.

Comment: Yea, forgot to add that. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use mod_rewrite:

Example of use (it is german, I did not found any better solution):
http://www.handcode.de/talks/phpug-mod_rewrite-20080312/slide-38.html